# mpirun not working after importing few specific packages

Tags: python, mpi, python-import, openmpi, mpi4py

I have two python scripts, one is being executed with mpi within another script using os module. Contents of both the scripts are shown below. Let package x be the one which is causing trouble and package abc be a random package. I have added commands "type mpirun" and "mpirun hostname" to show what is changing.

runscript.py:

```
import os

# importing a normal package abc
import abc
os.system("type mpirun")
os.system("mpirun hostname")
os.system("mpirun -n 5 python hello.py")

# importing package x
import x
os.system("type mpirun")
os.system("mpirun hostname")
os.system("mpirun -n 5 python hello.py")
```

hello.py:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import x
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
print(comm.rank)
```

Output of the command "python runscript.py":

```
mpirun is /home/pavan/packages/openmpi-4.0.7/opt-gfortran/bin/mpirun
skynet
skynet
skynet
skynet
skynet
skynet
skynet
skynet
skynet
skynet
2
3
4
1
0
mpirun is /home/pavan/packages/openmpi-4.0.7/opt-gfortran/bin/mpirun
```

As can be seen in output, if I import a specific package, the "mpirun hostname" doesn't print anything and hello.py script is also not executed but "type mpirun" is printing the same location for openmpi. I don't know why importing that specific package causes this problem. This doesn't happen when I import a random package abc.

Also, note that script that is being executed by mpirun is also importing that specific package x, but the script is executed properly. The issue only happens in the runscript.py

Any help on this strange error will be appreciated!! Also, what does it mean when "mpirun hostname" command doesn't output anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the root cause is package `x` imports `MPI` (from `mpi4py`).

Under the hood, that means that your program first start as a sequential program, and it is hence valid to `system("mpirun ...")`.

Once `MPI` is imported (indirectly via package `x`), `runscript.py` becomes a MPI singleton and is no more allowed to `system("mpirun ...").

Before `import x`, you can insert the following lines

```
import mpi4py
mpi4py.rc.initialize=False
mpi4py.rc.finalize=False
```

and see if it helps.

Note that this works for me with a simple test, but that will "broke" package `x` if it (indirectly) issues MPI calls such as accessing MPI.COMM_WORLD.rank.

The program below illustrates this.

```
import os
os.system("mpirun -n 1 hostname")

print('after mpi4py')
# make sure `MPI_Init()` is not invoked under the hood
import mpi4py
mpi4py.rc.initialize=False
mpi4py.rc.finalize=False

from mpi4py import MPI

# since `mpi4py` was not initialized, the following call will crash the program if uncommented
#print(MPI.COMM_WORLD.rank)

os.system("mpirun -n 1 hostname")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I think package x uses mpi4py and I don't want to break it. Is there any other work around for this?

Comment: You should first give it a try and see how it goes. If the infamous package does not make MPI calls when imported, you should be fine.

Comment: I tried your workaround and got an error: "The MPI_Comm_size() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked." So, the package is making MPI calls.

Comment: You can either update package x so it does not invoke MPI subroutines unless initialized (the `C` primitive is `MPI_Is_initialized()`, or replace `os.system("mpirun ...")` with the equivalent of the `C` `MPI_Comm_spawn()` subroutine. If the latter, you should also update `hello.py` and call the `mpi4py` equivalent of `MPI_Comm_disconnect()` before `MPI_Finalize()`